# rstudio server and access of remote databases

Tags: r, rstudio-server

I understand that several users can use an rstudio server. usually when we work locally we are already connected the to our databases (sql server) via active directory. How would this work in the server scenario. Would users have to enter credentials? I think one can also deploy plumber apis. How can they issue credentials to the remote database please? Thanks.

Comment: This seems like a better question for the RStudio community: https://community.rstudio.com/

Comment: @MrFlick sorry why is there a rstudio-server tag here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably depends if your solution is a free or a pro server. If pro, then better ask RStudio for sure.

For free server, some hints to answer something in case it helps you.
Docs are available here about that:

- ODBC pro drivers: https://docs.rstudio.com/pro-drivers/installation/ there is a point for MS server
- You can specify databases in odbc config file or just use `odbc::odbc` function inside R
- Then credentials can be passed in odbc package. You can prompt for pwd interactively, see [here](https://guillaumepressiat.github.io/blog/2019/11/oraclyr#decomposing-the-connection-string) for instance (in this case on an oracle db).

For credentials related to AD auto connect, I don't know, for me, users needs to identify to the database individually. It depends, first question is maybe: is your server configured to use the AD?

For plumber apis, unsecure ones are easily done but securing it yourself (jwt token or other IDs) without Rstudio pro seems not so easy.

Comment: thanks - appreciated. I am not sure why people voted to close ...